# Why does my countdown timer in my app not stop?

Tags: android, timer

I have a countdown timer which runs as soon as the generate expression button is clicked. Inside the timer I have made it work so when the timer runs it automatically clicks the button , so that the next expression is displayed. When the button is clicked 10 times it should start a new activity. But the problem I'm having is when the new activity has started it keeps starting the same activity. So i wanted the timer to stop as soon as the button has been clicked 10 times. I have tried `countDownTimer.cancel();` to stop the timer as soon as 10 clicks have been clicked, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is where the timer code is add:

```
public void generate_Clicked(View v){  // When Generate button is clicked

    if(gencount <10){
        if (!timerHasStarted) {
            countDownTimer.start();
            timeText.setText(timeText.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));
            timerHasStarted = true;
        } 
        else {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerHasStarted = false;

        }


        // Fetch your random question 
        String Rquestion = multiArray[ar.get(gencount)][0];
        displayExpression.setText(Rquestion);
        displayAnswer.setText("");
        setAnswer.setText("?");
        setHints.setText("");

        count =0;
        gencount++;

        }else{
            // countDownTimer.cancel(); //This doesn't seem to work
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Score.class);
            startActivity(i);
            ar.clear();

        }

}   //End of generate_Clicked.
```

Heres the timer code:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timeText.setText("Time's up!");
        Button buttonGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_gen);
        buttonGenerate.performClick();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timeText.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: To clarify, when you open the Score Activity, it reopens the Activity with the Countdown?

Comment: am not sure but you call `countDownTimer.start();` on `onFinish`

Comment: Yes, it reopens the score activity.

Comment: @SaifHamed When i remove this from there it doesn't `buttonGenerate.performClick();`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the CountDownTimer code, that prevents it from stopping. The cancel method does not work.

If you google you will see plenty of people describing the same problem.

So if you only start the activity when the counter is exactly 10.

```
if (gencount==10) {
        // countDownTimer.cancel(); //This doesn't seem to work
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Score.class);
        startActivity(i);
        ar.clear();
}
```

instead of } else { it should work. and reset gencount when the button is clicked, and also you need to have a different way of executing the whole handling code.